# How to verify that a UDP port is open?

Tags: security, troubleshooting, udp

I have here a dilemma. I have a device that communicates to another remote device but there is a firewall between them. It's a UDP connection, so TCP utilities don't work to test if the specific port is open. I know that we could get that from the firewall but I don't have access so I have to prove that the port is not open.

The source system is a Windows 7 system and the destination system is a appliance running Linux.

Comment: Without access to the firewall, you really can't tell (unless, of course, your systems are working).

Comment: Questions involving networks over which you have no control are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: I would vote to leave it open.  I think this falls into the grey area, and it's a useful theory/troubleshooting question.

Comment: ...do you have control of the firewall and networks? If not, then this is off topic here.

Comment: This is by a now a lab environment, we are trying to simulate a future production situation. I would like to get a way to troubleshoot UDP sessions without have to parse logs on the server side. But thanks I believe that is not possible by the nature of the type of communication.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about networks that you do not directly control are off-topic here.

Answer (score 13):

UDP is obviously a [send-and-forget protocol.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectionless_communication) For example, during an NMap UDP scan, the only way to definitively prove that a UDP port is open is if you receive a response from that port. Keep in mind that many services may not reply to arbitrary data and require protocol or application-specific requests in order to warrant a response. Certain ICMP codes can guarantee that the port is closed, however. [RFC 792](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792) and [RFC 1122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122) give us some good information as to what to expect when a port is closed.

For example, an ICMP type 3 code 3 "Destination Port Unreachable" is, for all intents and purposes, almost guaranteed to be a closed port.

A full list of codes can be found here:

http://www.iana.org/assignments/icmp-parameters/icmp-parameters.xhtml

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will investigate more about ICMP type 3 requests.

Comment: @JoeliNNaBit  Also check this C code example on detecting ICMP response. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60649653/check-if-udp-port-is-open-with-icmp-in-c .

Answer (score 13):

This is a quick recipe:

1) Start a packet sniffer:

```
sudo tcpdump -n -i eth2 icmp &
[1] 1409
$ tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
```

2) Send an UDP packet:

```
$ echo reply-me | nc -u 1.0.0.2 1000
```

3) If you receive 'ICMP port unreachable', that UDP port is closed:

```
20:54:15.475211 IP 1.0.0.2 > 1.0.0.1: ICMP 1.0.0.2 udp port 1000 unreachable, length 45
```

4) Otherwise, usually either the port is open or something is blocking ICMP.

Comment: Since the source system is Windows 7, the Linux commands won't work.

Comment: Yes that's true but I will try to a virtual machine and check if it works.

Answer (score 6):

`"nc -uvz ip port"` isn't somehow accurate, you probably should use `"nmap -sU -p port ip"`, if the result shows "open" then the udp port probably is open, if it shows "open|filtered" then probably it is closed or filtered.

Comment: This is the best command by far which gives the status as you need.